# Attribute PasswordNeverExpires & UserMayNotChangePassword in New-LocalUser function not working in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Attribute PasswordNeverExpires & UserMayNotChangePassword in New-LocalUser function not working.

These attributes where working until, I restarted the machine. After restarting, I found these functionalities were not working.

I had certain network issues in my computer so, I manually installed the LocalAccount module.
Then, I checked the LocalAccount.psm1 file where these attributes where missing. I myself added these attributes but, I am not sure whether its syntactically correct or not.

Initial LocalAccount.psm1 file

```
function New-LocalUser
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Alias()]
    [OutputType([int])]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   Position=0)]
        [string[]]$Name,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   Position=1)]
        [string[]]$Computername = "$Env:computername",

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   Position=2)]
        [ValidateScript({$_.GetType().Name -eq 'SecureString'})]
        [array][system.security.securestring]$Password,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   Position=3)]
        [string[]]$Description=' ',
    )

    Begin
    {
    }
    Process
    {
    $cred=New-Object -TypeName System.management.automation.pscredential -ArgumentList "null",$Password[0]
    $Plaintextpassword=$cred.GetNetworkCredential().password
    $computer = [ADSI]"WinNT://$($ComputerName[0]),computer"
    $user = $computer.Create("User", "$($Name[0])")
    $user.setpassword("$PlainTextPassword")
    $user.put("Description",$($Description[0]))  
    $user.SetInfo()    
    }
    End
    {
    }
}
```

After modification

```
function New-LocalUser
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Alias()]
    [OutputType([int])]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   Position=0)]
        [string[]]$Name,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   Position=1)]
        [string[]]$Computername = "$Env:computername",

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   Position=2)]
        [ValidateScript({$_.GetType().Name -eq 'SecureString'})]
        [array][system.security.securestring]$Password,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   Position=3)]
        [string[]]$Description=' ',

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   Position=4)]
        [bool]$PasswordNeverExpires,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   Position=5)]
        [bool]$UserMayNotChangePassword 

    )

    Begin
    {
    }
    Process
    {
    $cred=New-Object -TypeName System.management.automation.pscredential -ArgumentList "null",$Password[0]
    $Plaintextpassword=$cred.GetNetworkCredential().password
    $computer = [ADSI]"WinNT://$($ComputerName[0]),computer"
    $user = $computer.Create("User", "$($Name[0])")
    $user.setpassword("$PlainTextPassword")
    $user.put("Description",$($Description[0])) 
    $user.set("PasswordNeverExpires",$($PasswordNeverExpires))  
    $user.set("UserMayNotChangePassword",$($UserMayNotChangePassword))  
    $user.SetInfo()    
    }
    End
    {
    }
}
```

Can anyone please check your localaccount.psm1 and suggest me where I went wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to alter certain bits in the `UserFlags` property of the user:

```
if ($UserMayNotChangePassword) {
    # ADS_UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE --> user cannot change password
    $user.UserFlags.value = $user.UserFlags.value -bor 0x40
    $user.SetInfo()
}
if ($PasswordNeverExpires) {
    # ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD --> password never expires
    $user.UserFlags.value = $user.UserFlags.value -bor 0x10000
    $user.SetInfo()
}
```

---

alternative for the above

```
$flags = 0
if ($UserMayNotChangePassword) {
    # ADS_UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE --> user cannot change password
    $flags += 0x40
}
if ($PasswordNeverExpires) {
    # ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD --> password never expires
    $flags += 0x10000
}
# if one or both properties are set
if ($flags) {
    $user.UserFlags.value = $user.UserFlags.value -bor $flags
    $user.SetInfo()
}
```

These are the values for the ADS_USER_FLAG_ENUM

```
ADS_UF_SCRIPT                                 = 0x1
ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE                         = 0x2
ADS_UF_HOMEDIR_REQUIRED                       = 0x8
ADS_UF_LOCKOUT                                = 0x10
ADS_UF_PASSWD_NOTREQD                         = 0x20
ADS_UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE                     = 0x40
ADS_UF_ENCRYPTED_TEXT_PASSWORD_ALLOWED        = 0x80
ADS_UF_TEMP_DUPLICATE_ACCOUNT                 = 0x100
ADS_UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT                         = 0x200
ADS_UF_INTERDOMAIN_TRUST_ACCOUNT              = 0x800
ADS_UF_WORKSTATION_TRUST_ACCOUNT              = 0x1000
ADS_UF_SERVER_TRUST_ACCOUNT                   = 0x2000
ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD                     = 0x10000
ADS_UF_MNS_LOGON_ACCOUNT                      = 0x20000
ADS_UF_SMARTCARD_REQUIRED                     = 0x40000
ADS_UF_TRUSTED_FOR_DELEGATION                 = 0x80000
ADS_UF_NOT_DELEGATED                          = 0x100000
ADS_UF_USE_DES_KEY_ONLY                       = 0x200000
ADS_UF_DONT_REQUIRE_PREAUTH                   = 0x400000
ADS_UF_PASSWORD_EXPIRED                       = 0x800000
ADS_UF_TRUSTED_TO_AUTHENTICATE_FOR_DELEGATION = 0x1000000
```

BTW. I would make both parameters `[switch]` instead of `[bool]` like this:

```
[switch]$PasswordNeverExpires,
[switch]$UserMayNotChangePassword
```

so you can either leave them out or add to the `New-LocalUser` function call

Comment: Is this correct "New-LocalUser $Username -Password $encPassword -Description $Username -PasswordNeverExpires $true -UserMayNotChangePassword $true"; this command creates a new user but the check box is not getting checked.  When, I try to run without boolean value like this "New-LocalUser $Username -Password $encPassword -Description $Username -PasswordNeverExpires -UserMayNotChangePassword" it gives the following error. "New-LocalUser : Missing an argument for parameter 'PasswordNeverExpires'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.Boolean' and t
ry again".

Comment: @ManojStack Made a little change to the code and tested. Please change your parameters from `[bool]` to `[switch]` as I have mentioned in the answer. BTW. Windows 10 including Server 2016 and 2019 have this module included. If suddenly this is not working for you anymore, you could also try to select a Restore point and set the computer back to when it did work, or you can download and re-install the [Windows Management Framework 5.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616)

Comment: @ManojStack When using a switch, you do not have to add `$true`. If the switch is used, that is enough. If left out on the call, the code will see that as a `$false`.

Comment: Theo, Thanks a lot for the inputs so far. Its almost working. The problem is, only the latest attribute is getting updated. For example here "New-LocalUser $Username -Password $encPassword -Description $Username -PasswordNeverExpires -UserMayNotChangePassword" only the UserMayNotChangePassword field is getting checked. PasswordNeverExpires left unchecked.

Comment: @ManojStack I have added alternative code for setting the flags you could try. Strange though, because I tested it on Windows 10 with PowerShell 5.1 and for me it worked and both options were set.

Comment: Theo, The alternate solution has worked. My machine runs on windows server 2016. Thanks for your time and inputs.